# .net application try to load dll from a different folder

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, console-application

I have a .net console application. I deployed it twice on the same server.

one is c:\DAC

another one is c:\DAC1

this DAC solution has 2 projects. one is the main proj, and another one is the class project.  in the main proj, I added a reference to te class project.

when I debug the code in C:\DAC, everything works, but when I debug the code in c:\DAC1, it try to load the dll file in c:\DAC. Why its not load files from its own folder c:\DAC1?

This is a very big application. I cannot copy all the code here.  I just need someone to point me to the right direction. I am clueless on how to fix it.

Comment: Check the paths that you set the .dll to open from. You may have to use absolute paths in both.

Comment: @EvanCarslake when I added a reference to a project, I set "copy local" to true.  I do see dll got copied over to bin folder.  Did I do anything wrong?